# I need to implement a hook function (hook_function) using the Zpoline suite to modify the behavior of system calls

Tags: c, linux

I need to implement a hook function (hook_function) using the Zpoline suite to modify the behavior of system calls. Specific requirements are as follows:

First I Install toilet:`sudo apt install toilet`

Modify hook_function: Modify hook_function in apps/basic/main.c so that when the ./mystery program is executed, the color of its output text can be changed. You can determine whether toilet was executed by checking the execve system call (system call number 59) and modifying its parameters to include the color option.

Compile and generate a shared object library: After modifying hook_function, you need to recompile zpoline to generate a new shared object library：
`make -C apps/basic`

Finally, can use the hook function by setting the environment variables LIBZPHOOK and LD_PRELOAD:
`LIBZPHOOK=./apps/basic/libzphook_basic.so LD_PRELOAD=./libzpoline.so ./mystery`

After running, I should see the output text color of the ./mystery program change.
like this :

[image]

I tried to modify the hook_function of main.c in the Zpoline suite.

[image]

I tried calling the execve method when the systemcall number was equal to 59, but it had no effect. I want to know how I can modify the hook-function so that the output text color of the ./mystery program changes.